# Use default controller container if Unity registered types has not got this current controller defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

First time with Unity,

I have set up a class like this and registered in global.asax:

```
public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IUnityContainer container;

    public UnityControllerFactory()
    {
        container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
      System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, 
      Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null ?
            null :
            (IController)container.Resolve(controllerType);
    }

    private void RegisterTypes()
    {
        container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, EFUserRepository>();
    }
}
```

Problem is, when the AccountController (default MVC project comes with) is called, it throws an error:

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll but was not handled in user code

I can see there is a method to check if a type has been registered, but when I have made that check, how do I force the framework to use the default controller thingy?

```
if (container.IsRegistered(controllerType))
```

Here is my routing, as you can see... I want the login page to be the first page people see..

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/",
            defaults: new {
                 controller = "Account",
                 action = "Login",
                 returnUrl = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implemented a slightly different attempt at the factory:

```
public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IUnityContainer container;
    private IControllerFactory defaultControllerFactory;

    public UnityControllerFactory()
    {
        container = new UnityContainer();
        defaultControllerFactory = new DefaultControllerFactory();
        RegisterTypes();
    }

    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext ctx, string controllerName)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.Resolve<IController>(controllerName);
        }
        catch 
        {
            return defaultControllerFactory.CreateController(ctx, controllerName);
        }
    }

    private void RegisterTypes()
    {
        container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, EFUserRepository>();
    }
}
```

still kicking up errors though... hmm.